# Function naming: WordCount() or CountWords()?

Tags: naming

In most cases, we put verb before noun when we're naming a function, which is clearly and explanatory, such as `OpenFile()` or `CloseConnection()`. But some verbs are nouns too, so we can see `WordCount()` or `SpellCheck()`, and so on.

I prefer `CountWords()`, putting predicate before object, which provides a consistent look with `GetXXX()`, `SetXXX()` and `OpenXXX()`.

Which one do you prefer?

Comment: If anything, CountWords with an 's' ...

Comment: "What do you think"? questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: 0% accepted answer! very bad!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `countWords()`. Other alternative for me is `getWordCount()`.

Comment: +1. For me, I'd also like to know if the counting is actually happening in the method or if it returns a cached result (then `getWordCount` seems better).

Answer (score 0):

I like getWordCount()
Apart from just the action, I like to prefix the function with an actual verb of the function in relation to the caller. setProperty(), getWords() [to return the actual list of words], createWordList(), etc, etc.